# Implementing a new scenario based on Veins example

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am working on the implementation of the following scenario using OMNET++ (4.6), SUMO-0.22.0 and VEINS-4a2 simulators: exchange of messages between cars which are in the same control area where messages represent the quality of the road.

So, I would eliminate the scenario of accidents between cars in the veins example.

Do I need to change the code of handleSelfMsg () in TraCIMobility and onData () in TraCIDemo11p methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accident-scenario included in Veins is only a very basic one as it only has a single flow of traffic.

As a first step you should create your own SUMO scenario. Tutorials how to do that can be found on the [SUMO wiki](http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Tutorials).

Your second step will be to understand how OMNeT++ works and how to write new applictions for your scenario. Here I recommend doing the [Tictoc tutorial](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/tictoc-tutorial/) and looking at the [OMNeT++ user manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/).

Further information about Veins can be found on the [Veins documentation website](http://veins.car2x.org/documentation/).